# Get two windows of the same document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

I can have document view in two separate windows of `MS Word` by clicking `View->New Window`. Trying to make the same with Visio. After I click `View->New Window` I got two document view in same Visio window. That is not convenient by working with two monitors. How to get two windows of Visio with document view in each of them?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some methods for opening several separate Visio windows:

**Method 1**

- Open Visio from the Start button
- Repeat step 1.

**Method 2**

- Open Visio
- Hold the  <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click the Visio icon in the taskbar
- This opens a new instance of Visio.

**Method 3**

- Open Visio
- Right-click the Visio icon in the taskbar and select "Microsoft Visio"
  — This opens a new instance of Visio.

Once you have the two Visio instances open, arrange them side-by-side,
then open the documents. Opening the same document in both is not advised.

Comment: But that exactly is what vico wants. I don't think it can be done in Visio.